# Why is "to eat" the indirect complement in "Have you had sufficient to eat?"?

Tags: complements, infinitive-clauses

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (page 1262):

> Infinitivals indirectly licensed by *too*, *enough*, *sufficient*, *sufficiently*:

> [i] [a] It is **too** late [for you to go out now].
> [i] [b] **Enough** people turned up [to form a quorum].
> [i] [c] The instructions weren't **sufficiently** clear [for us to be able to assemble it].
> [ii] [a] **Too** good [to miss __] is how I'd describe it.
> [ii] [b] The problem isn't important    **enough** [to worry about __].
> [ii] [c] Have you had **sufficient** [to eat __]?

> The underlined degree expressions license ordinary infinitivals,  as  in  [i], or  hollow ones, as in [ii]. The  complements  are  indirect  in  that  in  constituent  structure  they are not  dependents of the licensor, but of a head item  that is modified  by  the latter. In [ia], for example, the infinitival is a dependent of *late*, not directly of *too*.

1. Did I understand correctly that:
   1a. "For you to go out now" in [ia] is the indirect complement to "too", but not a dependent of "too".
   1b. "For you to go out now" in [ia] is not a determiner, modifier or complement to "late", but the dependent of "late".
2. If "to eat" in [iic] is the indirect complement to "sufficient", then what is "to eat" a dependent of?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148572/discussion-on-question-by-loviii-why-is-to-eat-the-indirect-complement-in-hav); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two examples that you focused on:

> [ia]  *It is too late* [*for you to go out now*].
>
> [iic] *Have you had sufficient* [*to eat* ___]?

The bracketed infinitival clauses are indirect complements.

In [ia] the clause "for you to go out now" is licensed by "too", but is complement of "late".

[iic] is tricky because "sufficient" is a fused determiner-head NP, understood as "sufficient food". The determiner element "sufficient", licenses the infinitival, but the infinitival itself is complement of the head of the fused NP, i.e. complement of understood "food".

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think H&P would say that there's an "understood 'food'" separate from "sufficient" and acting as the head of the NP; I think they'd say that "sufficient" is itself both the determiner and the head. That's how I read p. 332: "we analyse the construction in terms of fusion of the head with a dependent function  rather than in terms of ellipsis of the head." Is there something I'm missing there?

Comment: Could you help me please with defining licencors of hollow infinitivals? ---- "_Her father is a very easy person to get on with_." - the licencor of "_to get on with_" is the whole AdjP "_very easy_" rather than the word "_easy_". ---- "_The assignment was an absolute pain to do_." - the licencor of "_to do_" is the whole NP "_an absolute pain_" rather than the word "_pain_".

Comment: For me (AmE speaker), [iic] is completely ungrammatical.

Comment: @Loviii In your first example the licensor of the hollow infinitival is the adjective "easy". In your second example, the licensor is the adjective "pain".